# if clause with formula as condition

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, divide

In given query I want to give condition:

```
if mha(material handling area) has name HB1(mha='HB1') then 
CAST(SUM(minloc) - SUM(noinloc) AS DECIMAL(6,0)) AS '_FREe places' divide with number 2.
```

How is possible to writte that? I tried with IF clause but I get fail msg.

```
SELECT mha, locstat, loctype, SUM(noinloc) '_Kolli', SUM(minloc) '_Plasser',
CAST(SUM(minloc) - SUM(noinloc) AS DECIMAL(6,0)) AS '_Free places''
FROM L30T1
GROUP BY mha, locstat, loctype
ORDER BY mha, locstat, loctype
```

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: hei, it is in SMSS :D RESULT : SELECT mha, locstat, loctype, SUM(noinloc) '_Kolli', IIF(mha = 'HB1', SUM(minloc/2), SUM(minloc)) '_Plasser',
IIF(mha = 'HB1', SUM(minloc/2) - SUM(noinloc), SUM(minloc) - SUM(noinloc)) AS '_Tomme plasser'
FROM L30T1
GROUP BY mha, locstat, loctype
ORDER BY mha, locstat, loctype